# Why won't this ajax call work in this simple object literal ajax frame work for javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var ajax = {
xmlHTTP: function() {
    xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return xml;
},
xmlHTTPfunction: function() {
    if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200)  {
        document.getElementById("te").innerHTML = xml.responseText; 
         alert(xml.status);
         alert(xml.responseText);
     }

},
xmlHTTPopen: function(url) {
    xml.open("POST", url, true);
},
xmlHTTPheader: function() {
    ajax.xmlHTTP().setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
},
xmlHTTPsend: function(string) {
    xml.send(string);
},
ajaxCall: function() {
    ajax.xmlHTTP();
    ajax.xmlHTTPopen('testx.php');
    ajax.xmlHTTPsend('test');
    return 1;
}
}
   if(ajax.ajaxCall() == 1) {
document.getElementById("te").innerHTML = xml.responseText; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the functions refer to the `xml` variable which is poorly scoped.  That is to say, when you call `ajax.xmlHTTPopen` there's nothing to say that the xml variable has any value inside said function.

The simplest way to provide better scoping would be to define the xml variable as a property of the ajax object; here is an example with minimal changes to your code:

```
var ajax = {
    xmlHTTP: function() {
        this.xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xml.onreadystatechange = this.xmlHTTPfunction();
    },
    xmlHTTPfunction: function() {
        if (this.xml.readyState == 4 && this.xml.status == 200)  {
            document.getElementById("te").innerHTML = this.xml.responseText; 
             alert(this.xml.status);
             alert(this.xml.responseText);
         }
    },
    xmlHTTPopen: function(url) {
        this.xml.open("POST", url, true);
    },
    xmlHTTPheader: function() {
        this.xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    },
    xmlHTTPsend: function(string) {
        this.xml.send(string);
    },
    ajaxCall: function() {
        ajax.xmlHTTP();
        ajax.xmlHTTPopen('testx.php');
        ajax.xmlHTTPsend('test');
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note that, as you've written it, the `ajax.ajaxCall` is non-blocking, so it will always return 1 immediately, even before the response arrives (or is necessarily sent) -- to that end, you have to assign a callback function to the XMLHtpRequest object's onreadystatechange event, to handle the response when it eventually comes back.

If you change the third parameter of `xml.open` to `false` the xml.send call *will* block until a response arrives, in which case you don't need to assign a callback.  The alternative implementation may look like this:

```
var ajax = {
    xmlHTTP: function() {
        this.xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    },
    xmlHTTPopen: function(url) {
        this.xml.open("POST", url, false);
    },
    xmlHTTPheader: function() {
        this.xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    },
    xmlHTTPsend: function(string) {
        this.xml.send(string);
    },
    ajaxCall: function() {
        ajax.xmlHTTP();
        ajax.xmlHTTPopen('testx.php');
        ajax.xmlHTTPsend('test');
        return 1;
    }
}
if(ajax.ajaxCall() == 1) {
    document.getElementById("te").innerHTML = ajax.xml.responseText; 
}
```

However in my experience, this is almost never used in the real world.

**Also**: your code never calls the xmlHTTPheader function, although there's no harm in that.

I can't think of a better proposal given your current code;  have you looked at jQuery and its implementation of ajax?

Comment: Everyone tells me to use jQuery.. but for some reason I feel it would take to many kb's to load for simple web apps..

Comment: @Matthew you don't have to include it in your webapp, but if you download the uncompressed version you might get some inspiration from their code.  And the minified jquery 1.6.1 is 89K, about the same as a small image.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

1. You should really not be relying on a global variable ("xml") to tie everything together. What happens when you want 2 overlapping requests?
2. You're never setting up the "readyStateChange" handler.

Comment: what would you say would be a better way for me to handle the scope of the xml variable? should I use ajax.xmlHTTP() in place of the xml global variable?

Comment: If you look into how to create a "class" with prototype-based inheritance, that will I think give you a way to proceed. You may also want to consider looking at the way the APIs for XMLHttpRequest works in some other libraries, just as examples of the things people have found to be useful.